# What is the difference between < : direction and | pipe?

Tags: linux

I am learning about Linux to take the LPIC Lv.1 which is the exam of Linux these days.

```
$ ps aux > proc.txt
```

As you can see above, I made a file by the output of the ps command named `proc.txt`.
Then I tried to show the content of `proc.txt` as hit the command like this.

```
×
$ cat proc.txt > less
```

However, It didn`t work, nothing was shown.

Even though this worked.

```
◯
$ cat proc.txt | less
```

I thought pipe:`|` and direction:`<, >` both make the result itself the input for the next command but it is not actually.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Consider harnessing the power of search. https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` redirects stdout to a file.  `|` redirects stdout to another command.